# TypeError: admin.firestore(...).collection(...).doc(...).collection(...).doc(...).get.then is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm trying to code a function that triggers when a user gets a new comment and sends a notification.Comments are stored in `/Users/{userID}/Notifications/{notificationID}`. Users save their device notification tokens to `/users/{userID}`

This is the whole `index.js` file

```
'use strict';

const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp();

exports.sendNotification = functions.firestore.document('Users/{userID}/Notifications/{notificationID}').onWrite((data, context) => {

    const to_user_id = context.params.userID;
    const notification_id = context.params.notificationID;


    return admin.firestore().collection('Users').doc(to_user_id).collection('Notifications').doc(notification_id).get.then(queryResult => {

        const from_user_id = queryResult.data().commentUID;
        const from_user_data = admin.firestore().collection('Users').doc(from_user_id).get();
        const to_user_data = admin.firestore().collection('Users').doc(to_user_id).get();

        return Promise.all([from_user_data, to_user_data]).then(result => {

            const from_name = result[0].data().name;
            const to_name = result[1].data().name;

            return console.log("FROM: " + from_name + " TO: " + to_name);

        });

    });

});
```

And here's the `package.json` file. Everything is up-to-date

```
{
  "name": "functions",
  "description": "Cloud Functions for Firebase",
  "scripts": {
    "lint": "eslint .",
    "serve": "firebase serve --only functions",
    "shell": "firebase experimental:functions:shell",
    "start": "npm run shell",
    "deploy": "firebase deploy --only functions",
    "logs": "firebase functions:log"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "firebase-admin": "~5.11.0",
    "firebase-functions": "^1.0.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "eslint": "^4.12.0",
    "eslint-plugin-promise": "^3.6.0"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

Firebase gives the following error:

```
TypeError: admin.firestore(...).collection(...).doc(...).collection(...).doc(...).get.then is not a function
        at exports.sendNotification.functions.firestore.document.onWrite (/user_code/index.js:19:119)
        at Object.<anonymous> (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/cloud-functions.js:112:27)
        at next (native)
        at /user_code/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/cloud-functions.js:28:71
        at __awaiter (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/cloud-functions.js:24:12)
        at cloudFunction (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/cloud-functions.js:82:36)
        at /var/tmp/worker/worker.js:700:26
        at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:135:7)
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Change this:

```
admin.firestore().collection('Users').doc(to_user_id).collection('Notifications').doc(notification_id).get.then(queryResult => {
```

into this:

```
admin.firestore().collection('Users').doc(to_user_id).collection('Notifications').doc(notification_id).get().then(queryResult => {
```

> `get()` returns Promise containing non-null firebase.firestore.DocumentSnapshot
>
> Reads the document referred to by this DocumentReference.

more info here:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.DocumentReference#get

Comment: I can't believe I missed those parentheses of the function although I wrote the whole code over and over again ^^" Thank you so much, Now I feel I'm back to life :D

Comment: That's great, no problem!

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
 var response = await admin.firestore().collection('Users').doc(to_user_id).collection('Notifications').doc(notification_id).get();
 response.get("field");
```

Answer (score 0):

try this.

```
var response = await admin.firestore().collection('Users').doc(to_user_id).collection('Notifications').doc(notification_id).get();

 const from_user_id =response.get("commentUID");
```